# Nanoc Deployment rsync error (code 2)

Tags: ruby, rsync, nanoc

**I'm not sure how to fix the error I am getting when I try to deploy nanoc. See errors below.**

aliaas@Alis-MacBook-Air ~/projects/portfolio/2014_portfolio
❯ nanoc deploy --target public
Loading site data… done
aliflyn1@aliflynnaas.com's password: 
protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?
(see the rsync man page for an explanation)
rsync error: protocol incompatibility (code 2) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/compat.c(61) [sender=2.6.9]

Captain! We’ve been hit!

Message:

RuntimeError: command exited with a nonzero status code 2 (command: rsync -glpPrtvz --exclude=".hg" --exclude=".svn" --exclude=".git" output/ aliflyn1@aliflynnaas.com:/2014)

Compilation stack:

(empty)

Stack trace:

1. /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nanoc-3.6.7/lib/nanoc/extra/deployers/rsync.rb:60:in `run_shell_cmd'
2. /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nanoc-3.6.7/lib/nanoc/extra/deployers/rsync.rb:50:in `run'
3. /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nanoc-3.6.7/lib/nanoc/cli/commands/deploy.rb:89:in `run'
4. /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nanoc-3.6.7/lib/nanoc/cli/command_runner.rb:14:in `block in call'
5. /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nanoc-3.6.7/lib/nanoc/cli/error_handler.rb:70:in `handle_while'
6. /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nanoc-3.6.7/lib/nanoc/cli/error_handler.rb:26:in `handle_while'
7. /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nanoc-3.6.7/lib/nanoc/cli/command_runner.rb:13:in `call'
8. /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cri-2.5.0/lib/cri/command_dsl.rb:185:in `block in runner'
9. /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cri-2.5.0/lib/cri/command.rb:298:in `call'
10. /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cri-2.5.0/lib/cri/command.rb:298:in `run_this'
    ... 9 more lines omitted. See full crash log for details.

If you believe this is a bug in nanoc, please do report it at
-> https://github.com/nanoc/nanoc/issues/new <-

A detailed crash log has been written to ./crash.log.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with your server, rather than with nanoc.

Searching for the error that you are getting lead me to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/267154/protocol-version-mismatch-is-your-shell-clean), which has the following answer:

> One of your login scripts (.bashrc/.cshrc/etc.) is probably outputting data to the terminal (when it shouldn't be). This is causing ssh to error when it is connecting and getting ready to copy as it starts receiving extra data it doesn't expect. Remove output that is generated in the startup scripts.